# Winforms: Editable ComboBox bound to array with a validation, right way to modify items?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

(in real project i have complex forms bounded to complex structures) to keep things simple let’s review 
trivial sample:

Simplest form with editable Combo initially filled with some data from predefined array, user allowed to select item from preset or “rename items (replace values in array)” bases on some rule (in example below must end with ”Item”), changes must be “undone” if new name does not match the rule. At the end, i must have actual array, where all items matches the rule and selected item.

I have found two approaches to accomplish this, but I suspect both are not “right way”. From other hand task looks for me like “already 1000 times implemented by others”, is there other “standard method” to do it?

My solutions:

**1.Keep tracking of current item in TextUpdate event:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[] items = { "firstItem", "secondItem", "thirdItem" };
    private string lastSelectesItem = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DataSource = items;
    }

    private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem!=null)
            lastSelectesItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem as string;
    }

    private void comboBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var text = comboBox1.Text;
        if (!text.EndsWith("Item"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = lastSelectesItem;
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = comboBox1.Text;
        comboBox1.DataSource = null;
        var lastSelectedItemIndex = Array.IndexOf(items, lastSelectesItem);
        items[lastSelectedItemIndex] = text;
        comboBox1.DataSource = items;
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = items[lastSelectedItemIndex];
    }
}
```

**2. Tricks with CurrencyManager:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string[] items = { "firstItem", "secondItem", "thirdItem" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DataSource = items;
    }

    private void comboBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var text = comboBox1.Text;
        if (!text.EndsWith("Item"))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            CurrencyManager currencyManager = this.BindingContext[comboBox1.DataSource] as CurrencyManager;
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = currencyManager.Current;
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = comboBox1.Text;

        CurrencyManager currencyManager = this.BindingContext[comboBox1.DataSource] as CurrencyManager;
        var lastSelectedItemIndex = Array.IndexOf(items, currencyManager.Current);
        comboBox1.DataSource = null;
        items[lastSelectedItemIndex] = text;
        comboBox1.DataSource = items;
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = items[lastSelectedItemIndex];
    }
}
```